# Need to align a text without using tabs

Tags: c#, text, while-loop, alignment

So I'm making a project which calculates loans.  If I put in a large number the alignment goes to hell.  Any help would be great.

```
    private void Reikna_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        u = Convert.ToInt32(upph.Text);
        v = Convert.ToInt32(vex.Text);
        v = v / 100;
        Th = Convert.ToInt32(fjoldi.Text);
        f = Convert.ToInt32(afbAri.Text);

        int nr = 1;
        double heildarg = 0;
        double vaxtaUpph = u * (v / f);
        double eftirst = u;
        double upphaedP = u;
        string upphaedPrint = u.ToString();
        label7.Text = "Heildarupphæð láns er: " + upphaedPrint;
        label8.Text = "Greiðsla                 Afborganir                 Vextir                Heildargreiðsla           Eftirstöðvar eftir greiðslu";

        while (nr <= (f * Th))
        {
            double st1 = 1 + v / f;
            double st2 = Th * f;
            double st3 = Math.Pow(st1, st2);
            double st4 = v / f;

            double nedan = st3 - 1;
            double ofan = st3 * st4;
            double sum = (ofan / nedan) * u;
            heildarg = heildarg + sum;
            heildarg = Math.Round(heildarg);
            string heildarg1 = heildarg.ToString();

            double afb = sum - vaxtaUpph;
            eftirst = eftirst - afb;

            string prufa = nr + "\t\t" + Math.Round(afb) + " kr." + "\t\t" + Math.Round(vaxtaUpph)
                + " kr." + "\t\t" + Math.Round(sum) + " kr." + "\t\t" + Math.Round(eftirst)
                + " kr.";

            vaxtaUpph = eftirst * (v / f);
            nr++;

            richTextBox1.Text = prufa + "\n" + richTextBox1.Text;
            textBox1.Text = heildarg1 + " kr.";
        }
    }
```

It's written in Icelandic so don't try to understand what the variables mean.

Comment: *It's written in Icelandic so don't try to understand what the variables mean.* -> Why not write it in English for us so we *can* understand?

Comment: Couple of suggestions: (1) Use a monospaced font, or (2) A better solution is to use a table to display the data.

Comment: store textParts in arrays per row, determine max length foreach column, use PadLeft or PadRight to align correctly when concatenating into row strings.

Comment: Used the monospaced font and that did the trick, thank you Matthew

Comment: Also I was woundering, how do you put a comma between thousands in the printed code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the tab feature `\t` to uniformly provide spaces between each entry.

Comment: Have you seen the code, he's physically spacing them out, I just gave a programmatic solution. Eg: in label8 ! He hasn't specified where he needs spacing.

Comment: `string prufa = nr + "\t\t" + Math.Round(afb)`.

Comment: Ah. Okay. He is mixing spaces and tabs. Nice, confusing.

Comment: I've tried using \t but it doesn't seem to work when I'm using labels.